# heroku pg:transfer - receiving error during upload of postgresql db

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rails-postgresql

I am trying to upload my local database to production and I keep running into the following error while processing:

```
$ heroku pg:transfer --from postgres://username:password@localhost/blog_develo
pment --to olive --confirm appname
Source database: blog_development on localhost:5432
Target database: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL on afternoon-taiga-2766.herokuapp.com
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: reading user-defined functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined types
pg_dump: reading procedural languages
pg_dump: reading user-defined aggregate functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined operators
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator classes
pg_dump: reading user-defined operator families
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search parsers
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search templates
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search dictionaries
pg_dump: reading user-defined text search configurations
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign-data wrappers
pg_dump: reading user-defined foreign servers
pg_dump: reading default privileges
pg_dump: reading user-defined collations
pg_dump: reading user-defined conversions
pg_dump: reading type casts
pg_dump: reading table inheritance information
pg_dump: reading rewrite rules
pg_dump: finding extension members
pg_dump: finding inheritance relationships
pg_dump: reading column info for interesting tables
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "schema_migrations"
pg_dump: finding the columns and types of table "articles"
pg_dump: finding default expressions of table "articles"
pg_dump: flagging inherited columns in subtables
pg_dump: reading indexes
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "schema_migrations"
pg_dump: reading indexes for table "articles"
pg_dump: reading constraints
pg_dump: reading triggers
pg_dump: reading large objects
pg_dump: reading dependency data
pg_dump: saving encoding = WIN1252
pg_dump: saving standard_conforming_strings = on
pg_dump: saving database definition
pg_dump: [custom archiver] WARNING: ftell mismatch with expected position -- ftell used
pg_dump: [custom archiver] WARNING: ftell mismatch with expected position -- ftell used
pg_dump: dumping contents of table articles
pg_dump: [custom archiver] WARNING: ftell mismatch with expected position -- ftell used
pg_dump: dumping contents of table schema_migrations
pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header
```

This is a very simple app that I've just created in order to practice using an postgresql db (It only has two tables, articles and the migration).  Has anyone seen this error before.  And I'm trying to use pg:transfer to upload to the database.  Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

Database.yml

```
development:
   adapter: postgresql
   encoding: unicode
   database: blog_development
   pool: 5
   username: benjaminw
   password:

test:
   adapter: postgresql
   encoding: unicode
   database: blog_test
   pool: 5
   username: benjaminw
   password:

production:
   adapter: postgresql
   encoding: unicode
   database: blog_production
   pool: 5
   username: blog
   password:
```

And here is the Gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
#gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter'
#gem 'sequel'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: Can you please post your database.yml and gemfile here

Comment: OK I added the Gemfile and database.yml